# LWC SFDX source push error TypeError: LWC1009: decl.moveTo is not a function

Tags: salesforcedx, lightning-web-components

Getting a strange error while running the sfdx force:source:push command for an lwc component

[image]

PROJECT PATH  ERROR
────────────  ─────────────────────────────────────────────────
N/A           TypeError: LWC1009: decl.moveTo is not a function

Answer (score 12):

I found the issue. The cause is a css file I have in a Lightning Web Component bundle.
I had two declarations for the same selector in my  css

```
.slds-card {
    border: 1px #CFD7E6 solid !important;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
    background-color: #9298eb !important;
}

.slds-card {
    padding-left: 1rem !important;
    padding-right: 1rem !important;
}
```

Merging them into one solved my issue.

```
.slds-card {
    border: 1px #CFD7E6 solid !important;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
    background-color: #9298eb !important;
    padding-left: 1rem !important;
    padding-right: 1rem !important;
}
```

I wonder if this should be logged as a bug in sfdx ??

Comment: I'd say log a bug. Worse case scenario, they close the bug, but if it's reproducible, they'll likely fix it, or at least document it as a limitation.

Comment: Yeah please log a bug if you have time. The description of the error is not helpful at all. And you should be able to push an LWC component with the same selector in the css.